# How to use split function in firebase realtime database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the user id string in the database like this "1WZeRpklGEgd5zjdHqaGC8Fq1vz2_1" merged with "_" and a number, and I want to split it to get the user id in database rules then compare it with auth.uid, for example like the:

```
...
  "Tasks":{
     "$task_id":{
        ".read": "$task_id.split('_') == auth.uid"
         ...
      }
   }
```

Any suggestion or another way to accomplish this is very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#string_methods), there is no split() function on strings, nor is there any other function that allows you to extract data from strings.

I suggest using the **value** of a child to store the UID rather than putting it in the name of the key, and use that in the rule instead.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) shows an example that looks like this:

```
  "Tasks":{
     "$task_id":{
        ".read": "data.child('uid').value == auth.uid"
         ...
      }
   }
```

With this, if you have a child called "uid" at the location of the read, you can use that in the rule to check access.

Comment: Thanks for repling
I found this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#split link to the function but I don't know how to use it, my app became on the store and adding a child to the database isn't the best option.

Comment: That's for Firestore, which has a different rules syntax.  You're using Realtime Database.  The link I provided is relevant for that.